# add column with primarykey migrations on update cakephp

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0, phinx

I am writing migrations script in cakephp 3 using Phinx.
I need to add a column with primary key while updating the table(using update() command) using migrations.
But when I run the script, it created the column but does not include the primary key.

```
  $table->addColumn('book_id', 'integer', [
     'default' => null,
     'limit' => 11,
     'null' => true
  ])->addPrimaryKey('book_id');
  $table->update();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#tips-and-tricks):

> Dealing with primary key can only be done on table creation
>   operations. This is due to limitations for some database servers the
>   plugin supports.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function change(): void
{
    $this->table('table_name')
    ->changePrimaryKey(['column1', 'column2'])
    ->save();
}
```